# AM using The Mobile Vision Text API,I want to filter out only numbers but not every text

Tags: android

I am using The Mobile Vision Text API, I want to recognise and extract only numbers from the scanned image not every character in the image

Answer (score 0):

To get only numbers,

```
String str=data_from_received_detection;
String numberOnly= str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

OR

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
```

Comment: Hi Viraj,thanks for the help, but please what I actually want is for the camera to detect only numbers in an image, similar to the phone scanning feature in Truecaller App.Thank you